# Can't save process's output stream to file

Tags: c#, ffmpeg

I'm using `ffmpeg.exe` as a process and output the converted video to memory, then from memory I'm saving the data to a video file (this is the requirement I can't directly save the converted video to a file). But the conversion is not working for some reason, Here is what I've tried,

```
var ffmpeg = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/FFMpeg/ffmpeg.exe");
var outputDir = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/converted.mp4");
var inputDir = "https://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_10mb.mp4";
var args = "-i " + inputDir + " -c:v libx264 -preset veryslow -crf 26 " +
            "-ar 44100 -ac 2 -c:a aac -strict -2 -b:a 128k -";

var process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo.FileName = ffmpeg;
process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = ffmpeg.Replace("\\ffmpeg.exe", "");
process.StartInfo.Arguments = args;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process.Start();
process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
//process.WaitForExit();
Stream output = process.StandardOutput.BaseStream;
process.Exited += (sender, e) =>
{
    using (var fileStream = File.Create(outputDir))
    {
        output.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        output.CopyTo(fileStream);
    }
};
```

The output file `converted.mp4` is created but its 0 kb.

Comment: If `ffmpeg -i inputdir -c:v libx264 -preset veryslow -crf 26 -ar 44100 -ac 2 -c:a aac -strict -2 -b:a 128k -` is what is being executed, ffmpeg doesn't know what output format is expected and will abort. So, that's one issue, but the other (fatal) issue is that a standard MP4 can't be generated over a pipe, since ffmpeg needs to be able to seek over the output. Only some formats, like flv or ts, can be written over a pipe. If you want to generate those, add `-f flv` or `-f mpegts` before `-`

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, due to the length of the process, IIS is terminating the application before it can even do anything worth wild. That doesn't mean IIS cannot trigger an external program to take over for you, so mostly you are moving the process (.exe) from the IIS userspace, into a better suited and multi-threaded userspace. You can roll your own queue management system, but in the past, I have used HangFire since it is better suited for the task. Using hangfire, you can submit the job of converting a file and let it handle the user's request, and you would just put an entry in a database that shows the status of the data that FFMPEG is converting. So when the user refreshes the page, it will poll the DB for the information, and not the console output from the .exe itself ( that would have been wiped out from the refresh.)

https://www.hangfire.io/